# Maven not finding dependency with only jar file

Tags: spring-boot, maven, gradle, artifactory, artifact

I have a jar in artifactory without pom. when I try to download it from maven/gradle, it is not being found with an error "Could not find com.kroger.galactus:koop-order:unspecified". My question is, is it possible to download artifact from artifactory which only has jar file and no pom file?

edited:
since it is not possible to download without pom file.
I have a third party jar file which I need to upload to artifactory. I used curl -X PUT -u u:p -T Maven-Upload-1.1.jar "https:///artifactory/repo/Maven-Upload-1.1.jar", which uploaded jar file.
Is there other way to upload it so it can create pom file in artifactory?

Comment: Should have a pom.

Comment: Must have a pom

Comment: Simply no chance without a pom file... That means during the initial deployment something has gone wrong ...

Comment: I have a third party jar file, which i am uploading using curl. Is there a way to upload this jar file and extract a pom file of it  in artifactory?

Comment: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GenerateMavenPOMFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no POM, you need to create one. You can e.g. do this through the artifactory REST api, possibly through the UI as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabian mentioned earlier, this can be fixed by generating the POM for the library. This can be achieved by using this [Generate POM REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GenerateMavenPOMFile).